# Using ExtJS with YII

Tags: php, yii, extjs4

Does anyone have any experience using extjs with Yii? I am having some difficulty understanding what the folder structure should look like with Yii. I have experience using extjs with Spring MVC but unsure how the folder structure should look with Yii.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've not used ExtJs but I have used Yii. I'm guessing there's a single main folder for ExtJS. That would be best in `extensions`. Then in the code you can refer to any files within using the alias `ext.extjs`. Then to get scripts out and served you can use the [AssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/) to publish them to the public folder for serving.

Comment: Thanks for the response Paystey. I was looking more in line with using the ExtJS MVC folder structure and using Yii controller to handle the JSON being passed back in forth.